# Android spinner within a button onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am using a button created programmatically through java file. I am using button onclick listener to represent the functionality. Is it possible to add a spinner inside that button click listener? My Code goes here:

```
View.OnClickListener newtodobtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // it was the 1st button

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.priority, R.id.spinner1);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

If i use this code, i get following error:

> The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, int)

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Replacing by this

```
ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(YourActivity.this, R.array.priority, R.id.spinner1);
```

Comment: Error Faced:
The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, int)

Comment: That's why I said replace `this` to `YourActivity.this`. `YourActivity` means current `Activity.java` or current `Context`.

Comment: Hi, I have overcome that error by following code:
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
       ArrayAdapter <String> adap= new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, level); spinner.setAdapter(adap);

Answer (score 2):

instead of this u have to specify `<class name.this>`. Bcz if u provide only this then it will refer to button. Thats why its not working.